# Export a text file but keep editing the xlsx file

Tags: microsoft-excel

I use excel to generate text files that then get parsed as input to a database.  I am constantly annoyed when I have to save the xlsx file as a text file and close excel because now I'm editing the text file in excel.  Is there a way that I'm just not seeing to generate the text file but keep the xlsx file open in excel?

Comment: What is the relationship between the xlsx and the txt file? Is the xlsx just a "glorified txt"? Meaning you save it as txt and then open the xlsx again to continue working with it?

Comment: Save as TXT and immediately after save back as XLSX supressing questions/alerts. What's a problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need a VBA macro for that, which may look like this:

```
Sub WriteTextFile()
  Dim FilePath As String
  Dim CellData As String
  Dim LastCol As Long
  Dim LastRow As Long

  LastCol = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Column
  LastRow = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row
  CellData = ""

  FilePath = Application.DefaultFilePath & "\euth.csv"

  Open FilePath For Output As #2

  For i = 1 To LastRow
    For j = 1 To LastCol

      If j = LastCol Then
        CellData = CellData + TrimtActiveCell(i, j).Value)
      Else
        CellData = CellData + TrimtActiveCell(i, j).Value) + ","
      End If

      Next j

      Write #2, CellData
      CellData = ""
    Next i

    Close #2

    MsgBox ("Done")
End Sub
```

You may modify the subroutine as you wish, maybe adding "euth.csv" as
parameter or prompting for it.
If the spreadsheet has only one column, this code can be simplified considerably.

For explanation of the commands used above, see the article
[Writing to text files in Excel VBA](https://www.homeandlearn.org/write_to_a_text_file.html)/